# Root EVO 4G stock ROM?

Tags: rooting, htc-evo

I've got a Sprint HTC EVO 4G Wimax.  I want to get rid of the Sprint Apps to free up some space on the internal storage, but otherwise leave the phone stock for now.

I followed the instructions at the HTCdev website to unlock my bootloader and I installed Superuser from the Play Store.  If I can get an su binary installed, I can give root to Titanium backup and remove the Sprint Apps.  There is a [zip file](http://androidsu.com) at [androidsu.com](http://androidsu.com/superuser/) that I think I can flash, but that's the bit I haven't figured out yet.

Since I've got an unlocked, but otherwise stock phone, I guess I don't have a recovery image, since if I boot into recovery mode, I get a red triangle with an exclaimation point.

What are my options for recovery images?  Is there anything besides ClockworkMod or Amon Ra?  If I go with either one, how do I get it installed?

Or is there a better way to get this done?

**Update**:

I Installed Amon Ra and used it to flash the su zip file.  I removed the apps that I could without breaking anything.  I didn't free up any space I could use at the moment, but I'm happy to have them gone.

Comment: `I want to get rid of the Sprint Apps to free up some space on the internal storage` - just to note, removing built-in apps won't give you more internal storage space. Uninstallable "bloatware" apps are on a separate partition from user-installed apps, and the space of one doesn't affect the other (unless you repartition your device entirely).

Comment: @eldarerathis  Sadly, it seems that you are correct.  Deleting a built in app does not free up any internal storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are my options for recovery images? Is there anything besides ClockworkMod or Amon Ra?

A third popular option is [TeamWin Recovery Project](http://teamw.in/project/twrp2/3), usually referred to as TWRP.

> If I go with either one, how do I get it installed?

Since your bootloader is unlocked, you can use fastboot to install a recovery if you download it in .img format. You do this by downloading the recovery image to your computer, plugging in your phone, and executing:

```
fastboot flash recovery /path/to/recovery.img
```

from a PC command prompt while your device is booted into fastboot mode.

Alternatively, ClockworkMod and TWRP can both be installed from apps on rooted devices. For ClockworkMod you can use [ROM Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.rommanager) and select the "Flash ClockworkMod Recovery" menu option. TWRP can be installed using [GooManager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.s0up.goomanager) by selecting the "Install OpenRecoveryScript" option in the app's settings menu.

A third option is to get a copy of the recovery you want in a bootloader-flashable zip file. For the EVO it will be a file named PC36IMG.zip. You put it on the root of your phone's SD card and then reboot into your bootloader and it should flash it for you. I know that Amon Ra has been distributed in this format, but I'm not sure about the others.