# Is there an easy way to update my HTC Evo 4g to ICS?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, updates, htc-evo

I just got a Sprint HTC Evo 4G, and discovered it is running Android v2.3.5 (Gingerbread). I  manually checked for updates, which downloaded the latest security patch for 2.3.5 Gingerbread, but did not update it to a newer major OS version.

I did some searching about updating it to a newer Android version, but most of the articles I found either have [dead links](http://www.androidcentral.com/install-android-43-your-htc-evo-4g-lte-htcs-blessing) or require climbing up a steep learning curve to root and then flash(?) the device.

Are there any methods for easily updating to (ideally) Ice Cream Sandwich, without needing to learn the software innards of my device?

Comment: Is this the same as [HTC Evo Design 4G](http://www.androidcentral.com/ice-cream-sandwich-arrives-sprint-htc-evo-design-4g)?

Comment: @AndrewT. No, they're different phones. See http://geekaphone.com/compare/HTC-EVO-Design-4G-vs-HTC-EVO-4G

Comment: I see... then I'm afraid there is no easy way since it only supports up to Android 2.3.5 officially. You have to manually flash custom ROM by rooting it first. [This post](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30174/root-evo-4g-stock-rom) might help...